# Can GPL be re licensed?

Tags: open-source, licensing

If some incomplete software is released as GPL, is it GPL forever? Or can you re-license it?
Assume that all the code was written by only one person, they received no contributions.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, the close condition is 'Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq'.  Does this question not relate to software development in some way?

Comment: I found it puzzling too. However, folks on SO just luuuuve to close questions, so there's almost always going to be one.

Comment: Amazing question, I'd exactly the same, and I was looking for a clear answer as the one provided by @Flimm, thanks to both!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal issue, and not programming.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Today a certain base level of understanding of licensing and patent issues has *everything* to do with software development. We may wish it weren't so, but it is.

Comment: While this question has value due to good answers, it is no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow. Such topics are more appropriate on [opensource.se], [law.se] or perhaps some other [Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no way you can rescind the GPL on the software you have already given someone. The only way that license is allowed to be changed is to a newer version of the GPL. Whoever received it as GPL will always be free to use it and redistribute it to others under the GPL.

However, if you hold the copyright on the software, you can do whatever you want with it yourself. That includes releasing it to someone else under whatever licensing terms you chose. So if you want to change a future version to be BSD, or dual-licensed, you are free to do that. If you want to sell it to some company with a closed-source license, you can do that too.

A popular option lately is to release a GPL version, and sell more permissive licenses to people who want to use the software in a closed-source program. For instance, that is how Red Hat and Ada Core make money off of their GPL compilers.

Comment: @T.E.D. thanks for the answer.  Makes a lot of sense to me.  If I could extend the question slightly, where this software is called Widgeter Version 2, and Widgeter Version 1 was and still is fully GPL'd.  Would any of the contributors to V1 have any stake in V2? (they didn't contribute anything physical to V2)  Could they argue it's an extension to ideas they contributed in V1?  All V2 code is completely unique and we hold all copyright.  V1 was a project started and managed by us on our websites.

Comment: @Tom Gullen - I suppose they could try to argue that. If all code in V2 is really yours though (with none of their contributions), that's fine. However, if its closed-source you'd have trouble **proving** that to them, and if some of the new features are similar to stuff they contributed I could see where folks might get suspicous...and then raise a stink.

Comment: @Tom Gullen - Also, if the GPL version is popular, most likely what would happen is that the users will get annoyed that they aren't getting that new stuff, and will proceed to fork off of V1 and add the new features themselves to a competing GPL version.

Comment: ...and if its **not** popular, then nobody cares so you don't have a problem. :-)

Comment: I'd just like to clarify that in most cases Red Hat doesn't sell more premissive licenses. Rather they sell support for their products.

Comment: @Varun Madiath - That would indeed be what both of them will say if you ask. However, along with that support you also get a different license with the compiler/DLL runtime. If you want to develop proprietary products with their GPL tools, you'll need that different license (regardless of how much or little support you need). If it was an insignificant consideration, they wouldn't have bothered with the separate licenses.

Comment: @T.E.D I wasn't aware of them giving out proprietary licenses. Could you point me to which compiler they're offering a proprietary license for? I wasn't even aware that they made their own compilers.

Comment: @Varun Madiath - You misunderstand me. They don't give out proprietary licenses. What they do is release their work as GPL to the public, and then give more permissive licenses to paying customers. You can't write a proprietary licensed app that links against GPL, so if you want to do that you have to pay them. In AdaCore's case you get GPL with linking exemptions. In Red Hat (Cygnus)'s case you get LGPL on their cywgin.dll.

Comment: Ah I see, and I didn't know Cygwin was owned by Red Hat. I guess I learn new things every day. Thanks.

Comment: This part of your answer isn't correct: "The only way that license is allowed to be changed is to a newer version of the GPL". This is only true if the license distributed with the software explicitly said "you can redistribute the software under the GPL, either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version." If the project fails to specify that, then the software can't automatically be upgraded to a newer version of the GPL.

Comment: @Flimm - Hmmm. I see. That used to be an integral part of GPL v. 2, but it appears to now be optional in GPL 3. I was not aware of that. I don't think this detail makes my statement untrue, so I'll leave it. However, I'm bumping your note so that people looking for extra detail will see it.

Comment: If you look at the [GPLv2 webpage](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html), you'll see that the "or later" clause isn't actually part of the GPLv2, it's just part of the optional recommendation after the body of the license. Software only licensed under the GPLv2 is very common, for example, the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 42):

## Short answer:

As a copyright holder, you do not have to choose between licensing your project under the GPL, and re-licensing at a later date.

Once a piece of software is licensed under the GPL, it is always under the GPL. However, as a copyright holder, you may re-license under other licenses as well, if you so please.

---

## Long answer:

To understand the logic behind the short answer, you need to grasp two different concepts here: **copyright ownership**, and **licensing**. For completeness, I will also explain moral rights, copyright assignment and copyleft.

### Copyright ownership:

When Jill writes a piece of code from scratch, she automatically has copyright ownership over that piece of code. Copyright ownership means that non-owners must get the owner's permission before copying or distributing copies of that piece of art. Jill can now sell copies of the software at a price, and the recipients of those copies are not allowed to make more copies, as Jill still owns the copyright of the software.

(In the USA, the [fair use doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) allows people to copy creative works even without permission under certain circumstances, such as for research purposes. Other countries have similar exceptions to copyright law.)

### Licensing:

Jill may want to allow people to copy and modify her software, without having to ask for her permission for every copy. In this case, she release the software with an accompanying **license** which grants recipients explicit permission to copy and modify the software. Examples of common open source and libre licenses are the Apache license and the GPL.

Even after licensing the software under an open source license, Jill still owns the copyright of the software. Licensing does not affect copyright ownership.

If Jack takes the software licensed under an open source license, copies it and gives it to his friends, he is acting legally, because all open source licenses explicitly allow you to do this.

If Jack takes the software and changes it, the new version of the software now has two authors: Jill and Jack. The copyright ownership of the new version is divided between Jack and Jill, and only Jill has copyright ownership of the old version.

### Re-licensing:

Because Jill owns the copyright on her piece of software, she can license her software under as many different licenses as she pleases. For example, she can give a copy of her software under the GPL to person A, and she can give a copy of her software under a proprietary license to person B. This is called [dual-licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing).

If a non copyright holder wants to copy the software under the terms of a different license, they must obtain permission from all the copyright holders, unless the software had already been released under a license that explicitly allows re-licensing (such as the BSD license).

### Copyleft licenses:

Some open source and libre licenses require that the recipient only be allowed to distribute further copies and modifications of the software under these two conditions:

- the new copies are also licensed under the same license
- the source code remains available.

These licenses are called [copyleft licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft). The most popular copyleft licenses for software are the GPL version 2, and the GPL version 3.

If Amira releases her software under the GPL, and Jack takes that software, modifies it and redistributes copies under a closed-source license, Jack is acting illegally. Amira could sue him for violating her copyright. Here's how the fictional court case would go:

> `Amira:` Jack distributed a modified version of my software without permission.
>
> `Jack :` But Amira's software is licensed under the GPL.
>
> `Judge:` Did you license your modified version under the GPL, and did you provide the recipients with the source code?
>
> `Jack :` No.
>
> `Judge:` Then the GPL doesn't apply to you. Did you ask Amira's permission to do this?
>
> `Jack :`  No.
>
> `Judge:` Then you are in violation of Amira's copyright.

As you can see, you can never violate the GPL. Rather, if you do not meet the conditions specified by the GPL, then you do not acquire the permissions granted by the GPL. If you haven't acquired permission by any other means, you are violating copyright, not the GPL. In practise, however, people frequently say "violating the GPL", when they mean "not meeting GPL's conditions, and consequently, violating copyright".

Remember, a license only ever gives the recipient of the creative work additional rights, it never takes away rights. (This is not necessarily true for a EULA, though.)

So can Amira re-license her software under another license, even if the new license is proprietary? Yes, she can, because she is the copyright holder of the software. Amira does not need to meet the conditions of the GPL because she doesn't need the rights granted by the GPL. As copyright holder of the piece of software, she already has the right to release the software under any license she pleases.

Amira does not, however, have the right to revoke the GPL. If she wants the distribution of her software to cease, she must somehow convince all the previous recipients of her software never to exercise their right to copy the software ever again. On the Internet, this is an impossible task.

### Enforcement of copyright:

If someone copies a creative work without permission from the copyright holders, they are acting illegally. However, only the copyright holder is allowed to sue them for their infringement.

For example, if Corel obtains proof that Raj is violating Adobe's copyright by pirating Photoshop, they cannot sue Raj. Only Adobe can sue Raj, because only Adobe owns the copyright of Photoshop. This is true even though Corel would potentially stand to benefit from elimination of the piracy of Photoshop, as they offer a cheaper competing product.

### Copyright assignment:

Under copyright law, it is possible to transfer your copyright rights to another party. This is called copyright assignment.

Most employees have a clause in their contract specifying that the copyright of all creative works made by the employees as part of their employment shall automatically be assigned to the company. Most free software or open source software advocates find this is perfectly normal and acceptable.

Amira may sell her copyright ownership of her software to Jack if they both so wish. The fact that she had previously released the software under the GPL does not hinder her from doing this, as she still is the copyright holder. Of course, Jack, can never revoke the GPL on that version of the software, even after buying the copyright ownership.

Many open source projects, such as the Linux kernel, attract a large number of contributors. Every contributor to the Linux kernel retains their copyright ownership of their particular contribution. If Linus Torvalds wanted to re-license Linux, he would have to obtain permission from every single one of the copyright holders, numbering in the hundreds. If one copyright holder refuses to grant permission, Linus could offer to buy their copyright ownership for a fee, or could remove their particular contribution from the Linux source code. Otherwise, Linus does not have the right to relicense all of the Linux kernel, because he is only copyright holder to a portion of the Linux kernel.

To avoid this problem, many libre and open source projects require contributors to transfer their copyright rights to a parent organisation. Another benefit of assigning copyright to one organisation is that the organisation is in a stronger position to sue violators of the copyright of the project.

### Contributor license agreements:

Instead of transferring copyright rights to a third party, Amira can grant Jack full rights to her software, with a statement like this one:

> Amira grants Jack a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce, prepare derivative works of, publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute [the] Contributions and such derivative works.

Now both Amira and Jack have the right to relicense the software, or to sue infringers of the copyright.

For open source and libre projects, both copyright assignment and contributor license agreements are controversial topics. Contributors do not want to lose their copyright or to share their copyright with an organisation they may not trust.

### Moral rights:

In the USA, copyright rights and moral rights are distinct. [Moral rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights_%28copyright_law%29) include:

> the right of attribution, the right to have a work published anonymously or pseudonymously, and the right to the integrity of the work.

Even when you transfer copyright to another party., you still retain moral rights. Your moral rights protect you from plagiarism, and to a certain extent, from defamation using your creative works.

I hope this clears things up for you. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: "Both Jack and Jill have copyright ownership of the new version, and only Jill has copyright ownership of the old version." In absence of any clause to transfer copyright ownership to Jack, Jack only owns that which he _added_ to the work. Jack did not receive ownership over the _entire_ work simply by contributing to it.

Comment: Actually Jill have copyright ownership of the version she made. The part that Jack made is Jacks. If Jill decides to re-license her code under another license, Jill cannot re-license the part that Jack  made. As Jill would be on copyright violation on Jacks code. Copyright protects everyone, including the one that later added code.

Comment: @MaxxDaymon: I reworded that sentence to agree with your point: " The copyright ownership of the new version is divided between Jack and Jill"

Answer (score 4):

The person who wrote the code is the copyright holder. They are free to distribute it under any licenses they wish, so if they want to re-release a version under a BSD license, they can. [Standard disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, blah blah.]

Answer (score 2):

Once GPL, always GPL. You can not change the license later!

Once you finish the app it must stay GPL. However if you wish to also sell it under some commercial license, that is fine.  Notice the word ALSO.  This means that you will still have to give it away under GPL!!

You may ask who will buy your app under the commercial license if you also have to give it away under the GPL.  The answer is: developers and people that want support.

**EDIT:**
Copyright holder or not, if he distributes the new version under a different license and if the new version contains code that was once released under the GPL, he has to give away all of the new code also under the GPL. The only way he can escape this is if the new version does not use any GPL code. The GPL doesn't just state what rights/limits "non-original" authors have but all authors.

The point of the GPL is that anyone can be an author and thus shall claim no copyright privileges because copy right privileges prevent free sharing and modification. Thus while the original author may have a copyright he gives away almost all privileges of copyright under the GPL.  Once that is done it can NOT be taken back.  The GPL is clear about this. I don't know any GPL project that changed to closed source only... in fact the GPL and GPL FAQ specifically state this can't be done.

If you are the original author, I believe the only copyright right you retain is to also release the product under other licenses, but you still have to release the entire work under the GPL as well.  of course you can only do so if in the commercial version you don't have any GPL code contributed by non employees before the transition, otherwise you have to get their permission.

Comment: I'd say close, but not exactly. As the copyright holder, you don't *have* to do anything. The GPL only dictates the behavior of the recipients of the software, not the author. However, once it's out as GPL, the copyright holder can't really stop holders of a GPL licensed copy from redistributing to others using that license (that's the point of the license). So no matter what you do, there will probably still be GPL copies floating around competing with you.

Comment: @T.E.D. we are not concerned about earlier versions floating around, Sourceforge actually took the project down from their website for us at our request, but if someone were to request the GPL version we would happily distribute it to them as it is pretty useless.  A lot of closed source work has been done on it since.

Comment: @Tom Gullen - Actually, if someone requests the GPL version from you and you are the copyright holder, you are perfectly free to tell them to go jump in a lake. The only obligation the GPL puts on anybody kicks in only when non-copyright holders (like say SorceForge) redistribute the software (or something linked with it) to somebody else.

Comment: Post edited why my comments to T.E.D.

Comment: This statement is false: "Copyright holder or not, if he distributes the new version under a different license and if the new version contains code that was once released under the GPL, he has to give away all of the new code also under the GPL. " If you own the copyright of a piece of code, you can change it and release it under a closed-source or permissive license, regardless of whether or not you had previously released previous versions of that software under the GPL.

Comment: @Flimm - Exactly. Licensing something with the GPL doesn't put any restrictions or obligations whatsoever on the actual copyright holder (Some Free Software projects, like Linux, try get around this little loophole by having multiple different people copyright the files).

Comment: Yeah, this is incorrect; the GPL only dictates what you're allowed to do to _other_ people's code.  You can do absolutely anything with your own.  The GPL tends to cement because most serious projects involve lots of mutual code use, and you'd need too many people's approval to relicense - but if you **did** get their approval, you could indeed stop releasing new versions under the GPL, even on e.g. the linux kernel.  The GPL is only 'perpetual' for new versions if you still want to use someone's code, and they're only offering under the GPL.

Comment: Not quite once GPL always GPL. The person might release a GPL version adn then decide to offer a version (of his/her own code) under another license. The person might also decide not to continue with the GPL version on newer releases. Only the version released under the GPL remains GPL.

Comment: The answer should be seriously revised or removed altogether. As others have mentioned, most of this is questionable at best.